# Python: MQTT, 2nd process cannot interfere the 1st process

Tags: python, subprocess, mqtt

I have an mqtt (paho) file which listens to iot message, then execute some action. In a test project, I have 2 processes, one is "play audio", and one is "stop" that process

```
def on_connect(self, mosq, obj, rc):
    mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC_START, 0)
    mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC_STOP, 0)

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
    print "Topic: " + str(msg.topic)
    print "QoS: " + str(msg.qos)
    print "Payload: " + str(msg.payload)
    iot_data = json.loads(str(msg.payload))

    if (iot_data["action"]== 'capture'):
        subprocess.call('python play_audio.py', shell=True)
    elif (iot_data["action"]== 'stop'):
        subprocess.call('pkill -f play_audio.py', shell=True)
```

The 1st process (play audio) worked perfectly, but 2nd process can only be called after 1st process is finished. Therefore, 2nd process cannot stop the "play audio".

How can I stop the 1st process "play audio" by 2nd process?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just an observation, if the action is starting a separate python process, why not import the necessary python methods into this script and use a separate thread for execution? That way you would not need to start a separate process with `subprocess`

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call()` is synchronous. From the manual (emphasis mine):

> Run the command described by args. **Wait for command to complete**, then return the returncode attribute.

You want an asynchronous call, so use [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Comment: I think the issue came from: mqttc.loop_forever(). It won't process another iot message unless the previous message completed.